# Where should I write typescript code for index.html in angular 4

Tags: angular

My navbar code will be same for all the pages....so I included the HTML for navbar in index.html and styles in styles.css of angular 4 src directory but where do I write the typescript code for this index.html file. I need to call the iconAnimate() function on clicking the #nav-icon element.

Below is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Wiz</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!--Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="logo-container">
    <img src="../../../assets/images/logo.png" id="logo">
    <div (click)="iconAnimate()" id="nav-icon">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<app-home></app-home>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should create nav controller and put your code over there,not in the index.html

Comment: Why isn't your navbar with the rest of your app, in `<app-home>`? And why are you not simply using Angular-cli, which manages all this for you and generates modules, components, services and other stuff so nicely?

Comment: What does the `iconAnimate()` method do  (I get that it animates the icon, but how)  and can you use pure JavaScript to achieve its functionality?

Comment: @DGarvanski iconAnimate() function just toggles the class name on click #nav-icon element and the rest will taken care by css

Answer (score 1):

Angular 4 recommends component based architecture.
So, Every thing should be a component(A component should have its own HTML,CSS,Typescript).
Since, you are using app-home component in your index file. 
I am assuming you have app-home component(.css , .html , .ts files).
Put navbar html in app-home.html and add the click event in app-home.ts.

PS: If you are new to angular 2/4, use angular cli.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for your purpose its best to use the `app.component.html` file to place that code. This component by default gets displayed once your application is run, so place your navbar HTML code in there, and the corresponding Typescript code in your `app.component.ts` file. If you'd like the click method to work you'd probably want to place the code for your animation on the div in your `app.component.css` file.

Its probably best to import your Bootstrap code in `styles.css` but you if you'd like to include the HTML reference for the CDN, pop that in `app.component.html` too.

Answer (score -2):

You should make everything a component-template with it's own (typescript) component (like a controller).

On the index, try to load your app into: `<app-root></app-root>`...

I think you are getting of a bit wrong. Check the documentation or tutorial of Angular 4. It will clarify what I mean here!